# Using getlementbyclass name or getlementbytag to scrape data from html content

Tags: php, regex, dom

Here I have taken source code snipper from webpage : http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80.

I want to scrape date, review, rate for each block on the page.

@: http://ideone.com/fork/Yfw2re

I am not much familiar with DOM element, I appreciate if someone can correct this

Here is the code :

```
<?php

// your code goes here    
$html = <<< EOF    
<div class="review-wrapper">
           <div class="review-content">
        <div class="biz-rating biz-rating-very-large clearfix">
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">

    <div class="rating-very-large">
    <i class="star-img stars_5" title="5.0 star rating">
        <img alt="5.0 star rating" class="offscreen" height="303" src="http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/c2252a4cd43e/ico/stars/v2/stars_map.png" width="84">
    </i>
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5.0">
</div>   
    </div>
        <span class="rating-qualifier">
        <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-10-28">
    10/28/2013
</span>    
</div>   
            <p class="review_comment ieSucks" itemprop="description" lang="en">The reason I started a yelp account, was to write a review for Franchinos. This is my favorite restaurant in the city of San Francisco, and especially, North Beach. <br><br>Where do I start... I take every friend, family member and acquaintance to Franchinos in every opportunity I can. I am a Italy-nut and have been over three times - the mood + atmosphere is almost identical. It is a 100% family-run restaurant and you can taste the expertise and &#39;home-cooking&#39;. <br><br>Each time, I get a large bottle of wine (One time - they ran out of the wine I had ordered - and instead gave me a larger, more expensive bottle - same price), a wonderful pasta dish (Alfredo, carbonara.. etc.) and a Caesar salad.<br><br>Need I say more? Buenisimo. I look forward to the next time.. and the times after that again and again. <br><br>è perfetto!</p>     
</div>
<div class="review-footer clearfix">
               <div class="rateReview ufc-feedback clearfix" data-review-id="SnZ4Q97nJdR7a-fot-Slcw">
                <p class="review-intro review-message">
    Was this review &hellip;?
</p>
EOF;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);    
$classname = 'review-content'
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$tmp_dom = new DOMDocument();      
foreach($nodes as $result) {
 
  //getting rate value from '<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5.0">'
  //getting  date from <span class="rating-qualifier">       <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-10-28">     10/28/2013 </span>
  //getting review from  ' <p class="review_comment ieSucks" itemprop="description" lang="en">The reason I started a yelp account, was to write a review for Franchinos. This is my favorite restaurant in the city of San Francisco, and especially, North Beach. <br><br>Where do I start... I take every friend, family member and acquaintance to Franchinos in every opportunity I can. I am a Italy-nut and have been over three times - the mood + atmosphere is almost identical. It is a 100% family-run restaurant and you can taste the expertise and &#39;home-cooking&#39;. <br><br>Each time, I get a large bottle of wine (One time - they ran out of the wine I had ordered - and instead gave me a larger, more expensive bottle - same price), a wonderful pasta dish (Alfredo, carbonara.. etc.) and a Caesar salad.<br><br>Need I say more? Buenisimo. I look forward to the next time.. and the times after that again and again. <br><br>è perfetto!</p> '
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop through the `class` values or `tag` names like this :

```
$classname = 'rating-qualifier';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}


$classname = 'review_comment ieSucks';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

$meta = $dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName("meta");
echo $meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
```

you can obviously loop the rating part to get all the ratings on the page using a simple `for` loop.

demo here : https://eval.in/143036

Comment: can I apply this to source code of  http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80. page? and also can you please give hint for rate too

Comment: @user123 may be a restriction of the website, try it on your local machine

Comment: or maybe curl the page beforehand and the read the contents using your command

Comment: it gives warnings for source code error like `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 700 in F:\wamp\www\htdocs\thenwat\yelp.php on line 6` if I use file_get_content.

Comment: okay it think there is some character in the html which makes the string terminated in between , you will have to find such `'` and escape them using backslash so that the whole html source behave as a normal string

Comment: @user123 are you on a linux based system ?

Comment: No on windows system: Here I used `escapeshellarg` and `nl2br` but no luck https://eval.in/143048 I guess linux or window should not matter

Comment: yes ofcourse it wont matter, I will work on this a bit and get back to you ,may be I am missing something

Comment: @user123 there are illegal /div and /li on lines 69 and 71 remove them

Comment: thanks, but it belongs the source code of web page. I am parsing the data from web page using file_get_content. SO it is not in my hand to remove it

Comment: thanks dude, but in laste update, did you updated the source code?

Comment: @user123 yes buddy I removed the /div and /li and then parsed the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51587/discussion-between-user123-and-aelor)

Comment: can you please help for parsing from entire page?

Comment: thanks for help. you initiated the solution. I reached at what I want

Comment: @user123 i think you got the final result in the third question you have asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341131/using-foreach-loop-to-scrap-all-class-data-from-page-source/23341283#23341283 you can mark that correct too :P

Comment: yes @aelor: but I have doubt in understanding the code. If you can rewrite the code with some comments explainatin then it may be helpful to me as well others

Comment: @user123 okay I will edit the code with comments and make it a bit easier to understand, actually its already divided in three parts but still i will add the explanation

Comment: code is nicely written, but due to my lake of knowledge I had some doubt, '

    if($html){

      $html->clear();

      unset($html);

    }' say about this too

Comment: @user123 Due to php5 circular references memory leak, after creating DOM object, you must call $dom->clear() to free memory if call file_get_dom() more then once.

Comment: can you please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391787/filtering-and-trasforming-number-using-regex