# Using foreach loop to scrape all class data from page source

Tags: php, dom, foreach

Here I am scraping data from web page using DOM. I can scrape the data for first class. I have put for each to consider all `review-wrapper` class. I think it iterate but every time it shows similar results only.

I am scraping review, date and rate value.

Example : http://codepad.viper-7.com/lHS9jk

code:

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html= file_get_contents('http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80');

$html = escapeshellarg($html) ;
$html = nl2br($html);

$classname = 'review-wrapper';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

foreach($results as $node)
{
    $classname = 'rating-qualifier';
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");
    
    if ($results->length > 0) {
        echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    
    
    $classname = 'review_comment ieSucks';
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");
    
    if ($results->length > 0) {
        echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    
    $meta = $dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName("meta");
    echo $meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you not just using the yelp API?

Comment: this is your 3rd question lol :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the for loop :

```
  <?php

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $html= file_get_contents('http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80');

    $html = escapeshellarg($html) ;
    $html = nl2br($html);

    for ($x=0; $x<=$results->length; $x++) {
        $classname = 'rating-qualifier';
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

        if ($results->length > 0) {
            echo $review = $results->item($x)->nodeValue;
            echo "<br/>";
        }


        $classname = 'review_comment ieSucks';
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

        if ($results->length > 0) {
            echo $review = $results->item($x)->nodeValue;
            echo "<br/>";
        }

        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $metas = $xpath->query("//meta[@itemprop='ratingValue']");
        if ($metas->length > 0) {
            echo $review = $metas->item($x)->getAttribute('content');
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

demo here : http://codepad.viper-7.com/C6KRW2