# Using something like getElementById for multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently using the document.getElementById("ID") method to fetch a value from an input area and paste it on a div.

This is working fine, but I would like paste these results in two different divs, meaning that I can't use the getElementById method.

I tried using getElementsByName but for some reason is not working.

[Here's my JSFiddle with the working code using GetById](http://jsfiddle.net/jhq4fk02/). What I would like is to get it to output the elements in both Output areas and not just the first one.

```
var counter1 = 0; //Prevents user from creating multiple nodes on submit
var limit1 = 8; //Amount of nodes that can be created per input field
document.getElementById('textInput1').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        createNode1();
    }
});
//CREATES FORMATTED NODE FROM INPUT VALUE
function createNode1(){
    if (counter1 == limit1)  {
    //Do nothing
    }
else {
    var input = document.getElementById('textInput1').value; //Retrieves input
    var newText = document.createElement("li"); //Creates the HTML node
    newText.innerHTML = input; //Sets the node's value to whatever is in the input
    document.getElementById("Form1").appendChild(newText); //Adds the node to the div
    document.getElementById('textInput1').value=""; //Clears text field after submit
    counter1++;
    }
}
//CLEARS THE FORM IF YOU MADE A MISTAKE
function deleteNode1(){
    var node = document.getElementById('Form1');
    while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
    counter1=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried using getElementsByName" — Not in the code you shared with us.

Comment: You could use getElementById for two different divs if you just gave them each a different id. `div1` and `div2` would be perfectly fine.

Comment: You can loop through classes and tags like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23333199/381802

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Do I have to use getElementById twice or get both on the same statement? Something like: getElementById("id1","id2")?

Comment: Two calls to getElementById. And I'm guessing that you are appending that `<LI>`. You would probably want to use `newText.cloneNode()` when appending to make a copy of the element for the second div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**USING IDs**:

Try this ... using two calls ...

```
Output1:
<div id="Form1"></div>
<p>
Output2:
<div id="Form2"></div>
```

... and ...

```
var newText1 = document.createElement("li"); //Creates the HTML node
var newText2 = document.createElement("li"); //Creates the HTML node
newText1.innerHTML = input; //Sets the node's value to whatever is in the input
document.getElementById("Form1").appendChild(newText1); //Adds the node to the div
newText2.innerHTML = input; //Sets the node's value to whatever is in the input
document.getElementById("Form2").appendChild(newText2); //Adds the node to the div
```

Basically, I've created two `li` elements with the value.  Then posted those to id's `Form1` and `Form2`

**USING CLASSes**:

If you had used classes, you could loop through the `getElementsByClassName`es.

Try ...

```
Output1:
<div id="Form1" class='formtype'></div>
<p>
Output2:
<div id="Form2" class='formtype'></div>

var classlist = document.getElementsByClassName("formtype");
for (var i=0; i<classlist.length; i++) {
  var newText = document.createElement("li"); //Creates the HTML node
  newText.innerHTML = input; //Sets the node's value to whatever is in the input
  classlist[i].appendChild(newText); //Adds the node to the div
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help ... which method did you go with?

Comment: I tried your first suggestion (using multiple IDs).